# Smartcard Authentication on EIDAuthenticate

Tags: authentication, driver, windows-8, smartcard, openpgp

Maybe I'm just a complete and utter novice but I'm really stuck with implementing Smart Card authentication for Windows using EIDAuthenticate.

I've had to download a generic (OpenPGP) minidriver for the card as it's practically unknown and no driver was available. However, I'm trying to put a certificate onto it, and it won't let me.

In order to write to the card, would the minidriver have to have provisions on it to do so?

Any guidance would be appreciated :)

Comment: Maybe it is practically unknown to you, but the card is *completely* unknown to us...

Answer (score 0):

OpenPGP minidriver is not "generic", it is for the OpenPGP cards (like CryptoStick or OpenPGP card itself)

Most probably you do need a specific (mini)driver for your card.

Answer (score 0):

You need a minidriver for OpenPGP card that is freely available from [here](http://www.mysmartlogon.com/products/openpgp-card-mini-driver.html).
I suggest to check my guide on how to set up an OpenPGP card with EIDAuthenticate: [link](https://github.com/djozsef/openpgp-docs/blob/master/Setting%20up%20EIDAuthenticate%20with%20OpenPGP%20card.md)